# Configure C compiler path in RStudio

Tags: gcc, path, rstudio

I have different gcc versions on my machine. I need to let RStudio use a specified gcc version for compiling C files. But regardless how I change the .bashrc file to change the default system gcc, RStudio always uses one version. Is there anyway I can configure the C compiler path in RStudio? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `CXX` and `CC` variables in `~.R/Makevars`, e.g

```
CC="clang" 
CXX="clang++"
```

Found here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200658807-How-to-pass-additional-flags-to-the-compiler-in-a-Rcpp-package-project